# How to join a column named "Identity" in SSMS?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to join two tables which have in commun an ID column. The problem is that for the second table the column is named "Identity". When I execute my code, SSMS tells me :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT*
FROM DET2_DAV_ASM_ENVIRONMENT DDAE
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON
        E.ID = DDAE.identity
```

Comment: SSMS is the interface for sql server. So which do you use, sql server or mysql?

Comment: `identity` is a reserved word and needs to be delimited.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this - `DDAE.[identity]` as identity is a reserved word so you need to use it in `[]`

```
SELECT*
FROM DET2_DAV_ASM_ENVIRONMENT DDAE
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON
        E.ID = DDAE.[identity]
```

Answer (score 0):

As identity is a key word so use double quote

```
SELECT*
FROM DET2_DAV_ASM_ENVIRONMENT DDAE
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON
        E.ID = "DDAE.identity"
```

Answer (score 0):

`identity` is a reserved word for sql you can change the column name or you can use it by `[]` like `DDAE.[identity]`